# Using test runners for two different tests JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have a class that I am testing using JUnitCore Test Runners to run the test. The program essentially removes every nth value from a linked list, it is very simple. I am testing:

1) See if the new list size is the size I expect it to be. 
2) See if an element was removed that I know should have been. For example below I know that "Item 1" has been removed.

I have been tasked with making sure that 1) will pass and 2) will fail, and all of this works, but on running my code, my problems are:

1) It is not a very efficient test and could be improved.
2) When 1) is True and 2) is false (as in code below), the output is just "False", and I am not sure if this is right.

I have tried when both classes are true and it returns True.

- Code for testing

  ```
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.Ignore;
   import static org.junit.Assert.*;
   import java.util.LinkedList;

    public class PruneTest {
     @Test
     public void testListSize() {

      LinkedList <String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();

      linkedlist.add("Item 0");
      linkedlist.add("Item 1");
      linkedlist.add("Item 2");
      linkedlist.add("Item 3");
      linkedlist.add("Item 4");
      linkedlist.add("Item 5");
      linkedlist.add("Item 6");
      linkedlist.add("Item 7");
      linkedlist.add("Item 8");
      linkedlist.add("Item 9");

      Pruner prunes = new Pruner();
      prunes.prune(linkedlist, 2);

      assertEquals(5, linkedlist.size());     
    }

    @Test
   public void testItemRemoved(){
   LinkedList <String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
   linkedlist.add("Item 0");
   linkedlist.add("Item 1");
   linkedlist.add("Item 2");
   linkedlist.add("Item 3");
   linkedlist.add("Item 4");
   linkedlist.add("Item 5");
   linkedlist.add("Item 6");
   linkedlist.add("Item 7");
   linkedlist.add("Item 8");
   linkedlist.add("Item 9");

   Pruner prunes = new Pruner();
   prunes.prune(linkedlist, 2);

   assertTrue(linkedlist.contains("Item 1"));
   }
  }
  ```
- Code for creating Test Runner

  ```
  import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
  import org.junit.runner.Result;
  import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

  public class PruneTestTwo {
    public static void main() {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(PruneTest.class);

      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
        System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }

     System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more verbose and useful output from your tests using the alternative `assertThat` method with matchers, rather than the older `assertEquals`/`assertTrue`

For example you could combine your two tests above and get meaningful output about what's failing like this:

```
   @Test
   public void testListSize() {

    LinkedList <String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
    linkedlist.add("Item 0");
    linkedlist.add("Item 1");
    linkedlist.add("Item 2");
    linkedlist.add("Item 3");
    linkedlist.add("Item 4");
    linkedlist.add("Item 5");
    linkedlist.add("Item 6");
    linkedlist.add("Item 7");
    linkedlist.add("Item 8");
    linkedlist.add("Item 9");

    Pruner prunes = new Pruner();
    prunes.prune(linkedlist, 2);

    assertThat(linkedlist.size(), is(5));
    assertThat(linkedlist, hasItem("Item 1"));    
  }
```

Then when the second assertion fails, you'll get output similar to this (which is much easier to understand than a lonely `false`):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing "x"
     but: was "Item 0", was "Item 1", was "Item 2", was "Item 3", was "Item 4", was "Item 5", was "Item 6", was "Item 7", was "Item 8", was "Item 9"
```

You could improve it even more by making sure the pruned list is exactly what you expect - instead of checking the size and one item in it, you can check the size and every item (along with the order of the list) by using the `contains` matcher:

```
assertThat(linkedlist, contains("Item 0", "Item 2", "Item 4", "Item 6", "Item 8"));
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense, I'll update my code and mark as answered.